# Extract multi values to point error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, sampling, extract-by-mask

I am trying to extract values from my rasters (slope, aspect, landcover etc.) for my animal group locations. I used Spatial Analyst > Extract Multi-values to Points, but when I look in my attribute table after the process the results are the same for all the points and make no sense. For example 0 for a landcover, -3x10-38 for a slope, etc.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

I am working with ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Are the points and rasters in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: This tool has always been buggy for me. You could create a model that chains together multiple instances of the "extract value by point tool"

Answer (score 3):

The tool you are looking for is the "Sample"(Spatial analyst>Extraction>Sample).
Add all your rasters, then the shape file with the locations.

Comment: Thank you! 
Now if instead of points I have buffers of different size, can I use this tool too? 
I tried using GME intersect polygon/raster but I get results as if I had no values everywhere on my raster...